# Is it Possible to Get Brep Name from GetSurfaces function? (CATIA VBA)

Tags: vba, catia

This is my first post on Stack, I wanted to ask if it would be possible to get the BRep name from the get surfaces function. Right now, I have

```
Set annoSurface = myDocument.Selection.Item(1).Value
        surfaceCount = annoSurface.GetSurfacesCount
        ReDim surfaceArray(surfaceCount - 1)
        annoSurface.GetSurfaces surfaceArray
        For j = 0 To surfaceCount - 1
            surfaceNamePath = Split(surfaceArray(j), "/")
            pathLen = UBound(surfaceNamePath) - LBound(surfaceNamePath)
            If surfaceNamePath(1) <> "Annotation Set.1" Then
                ReDim surName(pathLen - 2) As String
                For i = 1 To pathLen - 1
                    surName(i - 1) = surfaceNamePath(i)
                Next i
                surfaceName = Replace(Join(surName, "/"), surName(pathLen - 2), "!" & surName(pathLen - 2))
                Set surfaceRef = Product.CreateReferenceFromName(surfaceName)
                myDocument.Selection.Add surfaceRef
            End If
        Next j
```

In this code I am able to retrieve the instance name from the GetSurfaces api in CATIA. From there I am able to rearrange the name into a name of a surface that is searchable.

Ex. K0654-50-3567212-00/SLIDING PISTON/OPERATIONS/HOLES/BRAKE ROD BORE/Groove.3/Face -> SLIDING PISTON/OPERATIONS/HOLES/BRAKE ROD BORE/!Groove.3

Then I create a reference from the new name and add that to the selection. But when I add to the selection, it highlights multiple surfaces. I just want to highlight 1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daCoE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kanEI.png)

I am actually not sure where to go from here, I've seen that you can use BRep to specifically state the boundary of the surface that you want to select but I'm not sure how I can even acquire that from only the GetSurfaces function.

Comment: Sorry not possible. 
If the annotation was created from selection of a whole feature, i.e. if there is not /Edge or /Face, then yes you can imply the feature (Which is what you are doing). But when it is a topological sub-element (face/edge/vertex as it typically is) it cannot be determined from the returned user-surface string.